# How to qucikly check which range does a string fall into

Tags: java, algorithm

Considering we have a couple of ranges as shown in the table:

| Left Bound | Right Bound |
| --- | --- |
| 4000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 | 4500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 |
| 5000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 | 5500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 |
| 5600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 | 6000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 |

Ranges are not cosecutive. Given a string like `4111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000`. How can I quickly know which range does it falls into?

My current way is to use a List to store those ranges, and compare the given string digit by digit. If the current digit is larger/smaller than the same digit in current range, it'll check the next one. Is there a more efficient way to quickly find which range does the given string fall into?

Comment: Can ranges overlap? If so, is the expected output to give all matching ranges? Are all involved strings equally sized?

Answer (score 1):

The String class already does the same comparison (char by char) in its `.compareTo()` method. define a class "Bounds" with 2 strings "lowerBound" and "upperBound" and create a List and then you can simply check:

```
for(Bound bound : list) {
    if(input.compareTo(bound.lowerBound) > input.compareTo(bound.upperBound)) {
        // input is in this range //
    }
}
```

as far as i can tell, there is no solution in less than O(n*d) where d is the length of the bounds strings and n is the number of ranges.

Comment: If input is outside a range, won't this still return true? Both compareTo returned values would be equal in such cases.

Comment: right, i'll remove the equals sign, but then there is an assumption that lowerbound must be "less than" upperbound.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), and the corresponding `ceiling` and `floor` methods.

It does what you need efficiently.

### Edit

I misunderstood your question. `TreeSet` will work for a collection of "bounds", like a partition of your strings.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Elias suggested, you can use the fact that `String` are [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) but if the number of `Bound` instances increases, I'd go on a faster lookup algorithm.
Making few assumptions :

1. The bounds never overlap.
2. The lower bound always <= the upper bound.
3. The lower and upper bounds are always non null.

Let's consider you have created an array of Bound:

```
Bound[] bounds = new Bound[] {
    //....  
};
```

You have to sort it:

```
Arrays.sort(bounds, new Comparator<Bound>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Bound b1, Bound b2) {
        return b1.lowerLimit.compareTo(b2.lowerLimit);
    }
    
});
```

Then you can implement your lookup method wich is in fact an implementation of [binary search](https://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-search):

```
private Bound searchBound(String value, Bound[] bounds) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = bounds.length - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        //take the Bound index in the middle of the range
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        Bound bound = bounds[mid];

        if (bound.upperLimit.compareTo(value) < 0) {
            //look in the range after the current middle
            low = mid + 1;
        } else if (bound.lowerLimit.compareTo(value) > 0) {
            //look in the range before current middle
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return bound; // found
        }
    }
    return null;  // not found
}
```

...and you can call it that way:

```
Bound b = searchBound("4111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000", bounds);
```

Note that

- for such a small amount of items to lookup, it is utterly inefficient and complicated.
- you could make `Bound` implement `Comparable` to avoid the `Comparator`creation.

Another way is to use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which should look more simple and does not require sorting your array since its keys are sorted by definition:

```
private static Bound searchBoundByTreeMap(String value, Bound[] bounds) {
    //Create the TreeMap and populate it from the Bound array
    TreeMap<String, Bound> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for(Bound bound : bounds) {
        map.put(bound.lowerLimit, bound);
    }

    //Finds the first Bound where lower bound is smaller than the lookup value
    Entry<String, Bound> entry = map.floorEntry(value);
    //Not found
    if (entry == null) return null;
    
    Bound bound = entry.getValue();
    
    //We have checked the lower bound but not the upper bound yet
    if (value.compareTo(bound.upperLimit) > 0) return null; /// out of bound -> not found
    
    return bound;
}
```